# Permission Denied for driver-select

Tags: wireless, drivers

Currently I'm new to Linux. I'm trying to add in wireless drivers and everytime I try to select my driver i get this

```
./scripts/driver-select ath9k
bash: ./scripts/driver-select: Permission denied
```

Comment: try `sudo ./scripts/driver-select ath9k` As a normal user there are some things you cant do to protect the computer `sudo` says **I know what I'm doing: trust me.** and should allow the script to run.  Only do this if your happy the script is safe; i.e. you trust where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

just use **SUDO** which stands for "Super User DO" and give ur actions root-privileges. That should do the trick.So u just :

```
sudo ./scripts/driver-select ath9k
```

Have fun (-: